# Find the optimal way to use combinations of summands to get the most sum with a limited number of summands

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics

I have a bit of a problem, I have a set of sums that add up to X, like so:

A: $i + j + k = X$

B: $t + z = X$

C: $z + z = X$

D: $j + j + k + k = X$

I have a limited number of summands so for example I have: 12 of $i$, 35 of $z$, 12 of $j$, and 18 of $k$, 21 of $t$.

What I need is an algorithm that will determine the best way to use those combinations so that I end up with the most complete sums of $X$

So in the example above using:

17 of combination $C$, 1 of combination $B$, and 12 of combination $A$, total 30 sums of $X$, 72 summands used

is worse then using:

21 of combination $B$, 7 of combination $C$, and 6 of combination $D$, total 34 sums of $X$, 80 summands used

*EDIT*:

To further explain:

using 21 of combination $B$ will "spend" 21 $t$ and 21 $z$ leaving us with: 12 of $i$, 14 of $z$, 12 of $j$, 18 of $k$, 0 of $t$

using 7 of combination $C$ will "spend" 14 of $z$ (because it uses 2 summands of $z$ to be achieved) leaving us with: 12 of $i$, 0 of $z$, 12 of $j$, 18 of $k$, 0 of $t$

using 6 of combination $D$ will spend 12 of $j$ and 12 of $k$ (because it uses both of them twice) leaving us with: 12 of $i$, 0 of $z$, 0 of $j$, 6 of $k$, 0 of $t$

we can no longer make combinations that will add up to $X$ thus the algorithm is concluded.

Comment: this sounds like a variant on BIN PACKING, where the goal is to make as many unit size buckets (here X = 1) by combining elements.

Comment: Kind of a dual goal: here you do not allow slack in the bins, but you are allowed not to pack all objects.

Comment: @SureshVenkat well Bin Packing has similarities to this yes, I would love to use a Bin Packing algorithm if you know of one that will pack the objects in this manner, I don't... ones I know usually pack them imperfectly.

Comment: @MassimoLauria well yes if we pack all objects we don't get X, however I can easily discard results that don't obtain X if you have a solution that will pack all of them perfectly, but as I mentioned above Bin Packing usually doesn't do that.

Comment: The question would be clearer (at least to me) if you gave a general specification, instead of just an example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is a generalization of the [set packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) (exercise: why?), and therefore it is NP-hard even to approximate in a very weak sense.  See [Maximum Set Packing](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node144.html) and [Maximum Clique](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node33.html) in the compendium.

Answer (score -1):

Try researching [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).  Dynamic programming provides the ability to iterate over a problem set that involves multiple equations.  Also, take a look at [gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

If properly designed and implemented by setting the data up properly, gaussian elimination can intelligently reduce the number of combinations that the algorithm will need to look at.  In your example, a limit of 12 j was specified.  So, if one of the combinations looked at is 12 of A (which consists of i + j + k), then both i and j are exhausted since there are only 12 of each.  So, any other combination that uses i or j (like D which uses 2 of j) no longer needs to be evaluated since we know that this combination can not be used.